# QTreeWidget doesn't display QCombobox delegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I have the delegate class and method paint in it. I would like to show the comboboxes in the QTreeWidget columns and do for it

```
ui->treeWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, box);
```

where box is the object of my delegate

The paint method is

```
void ComboboxDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionComboBox box;

    QString text = values[1];

    box.currentText = text;
    box.rect = option.rect;

    QApplication::style()->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &box, painter, 0);
    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ComboBoxLabel, &box, painter, 0);
}
```

values is the QMap with two variables - "Hello" and "Goodbye"

But instead of drawing comboboxes treewidget shows just "Hello" strings in second column 
Why?
How can i fix it?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked OK. Maybe something is wrong with the brightness of your monitor? And which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget - This allows to to place a widget directly instead of using a custom delegate, but only works with treewidgets

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, i guess the problem starts with incorrect  qss. But i have no idea how to write correct qss for QStyleOptionComboBox or for ComboboxDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have qss files and want to customize your QComboBox delegate you should add some combobox in paint() method and replace that:

```
 QApplication::style()->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &box, painter, 0);
```

to:

```
QComboBox tmp;
QApplication::style()->drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_ComboBox, &box, painter, &tmp);
```